# Running Sum # and Running Sum % based on status Power BI (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, cumulative-sum

I am struggling with creating Running Summ for value based on two statuses I have in my table. The problem is that I do not have dates, only text and numeric values.

I even created Index table but this does not help. Please have a look at my data:

[image]

I need to calculate Running Sum for Column Distribution in another Column but for status "Gains" and "Gross" separately. So the Running Sum is calculated for "Gains" and then starts again for "Gross".

Then I need to use that to create Percent of Total - also separately for "Gains" only and for "Gross" only. I reviewed many forums, tutorials and could not find anything working for my data.

Can you please help me out?

Data sample:

| Score Range | tier | Distribution | Status | General Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-100 | Tier III | 38 | Gains | 1 |
| 100-125 | Tier III | 33 | Gains | 2 |
| 125-150 | Tier III | 49 | Gains | 3 |
| 150-175 | Tier III | 46 | Gains | 4 |
| 175-200 | Tier III | 76 | Gains | 5 |
| 200-225 | Tier II | 135 | Gains | 6 |
| 225-250 | Tier I | 348 | Gains | 7 |
| 250-275 | Tier I | 417 | Gains | 8 |
| 275-300 | Tier I | 541 | Gains | 9 |
| 300-325 | Tier I | 682 | Gains | 10 |
| 325-350 | Tier I | 910 | Gains | 11 |
| 350-375 | Tier I | 781 | Gains | 12 |
| 375-400 | Tier I | 754 | Gains | 13 |
| 400-425 | Tier I | 551 | Gains | 14 |
| 425-450 | Tier I | 396 | Gains | 15 |
| 450-475 | Tier I | 214 | Gains | 16 |
| 475-500 | Tier I | 50 | Gains | 17 |
| 500 + | Tier I | 2 | Gains | 18 |
| No Score | Tier I | 176 | Gains | 19 |
| 1-100 | Tier III | 350 | Gross | 1 |
| 100-125 | Tier III | 270 | Gross | 2 |
| 125-150 | Tier III | 404 | Gross | 3 |
| 150-175 | Tier III | 463 | Gross | 4 |
| 175-200 | Tier III | 465 | Gross | 5 |
| 200-225 | Tier II | 512 | Gross | 6 |
| 225-250 | Tier I | 599 | Gross | 7 |
| 250-275 | Tier I | 700 | Gross | 8 |
| 275-300 | Tier I | 897 | Gross | 9 |
| 300-325 | Tier I | 1089 | Gross | 10 |
| 325-350 | Tier I | 1415 | Gross | 11 |
| 350-375 | Tier I | 1183 | Gross | 12 |
| 375-400 | Tier I | 1104 | Gross | 13 |
| 400-425 | Tier I | 725 | Gross | 14 |
| 425-450 | Tier I | 535 | Gross | 15 |
| 450-475 | Tier I | 282 | Gross | 16 |
| 475-500 | Tier I | 67 | Gross | 17 |
| 500 + | Tier I | 2 | Gross | 18 |
| No Score | Tier I | 624 | Gross | 19 |

I am trying to make calculations as on below screen:

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: when you write that you need to sum the distribution in another column but for the status Gains and Gross separately, you mean that you need to add them to two separate columns, not in one, correct?

Comment: The index in your data is not unique, it seems to depend on the status, can you replace it with a unique index instead?

Comment: Hi, sure. I added an excel file with columns calculation I need to have in the data set. This is very dificult to get via DAX, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shortened the names of the columns a bit to make the result table stay in the answer
I named the sample data table "Status"

For the Running Sum we iterate filtering the Status of the current row and an index less than or equal to the current row's

```
Running Sum = 
VAR CurrentRowStatus = Scores[Status]
VAR CurrentIndex = Scores[General Index]
VAR Result =
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            Scores,
            Scores[Status] = CurrentRowStatus
                && Scores[General Index] <= CurrentIndex
        ),
        Scores[Distribution]
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

For the percentages calculated columns we need to compute the total, therefore we use MAXX over the Status table filtered using the current row status

```
percent = 
VAR CurrentRowStatus = Scores[Status]
VAR Total =
    MAXX(
        FILTER( Scores, Scores[Status] = CurrentRowStatus ),
        Scores[Running Sum]
    )
VAR Result =
    DIVIDE( Scores[Distribution], Total )
RETURN
    Result
```

the cumulative percent calculated column is similar, it just uses the Running Sum calculated column instead of the Distribution

```
cumulative percent = 
VAR CurrentRowStatus = Scores[Status]
VAR Total =
    MAXX(
        FILTER( Scores, Scores[Status] = CurrentRowStatus ),
        Scores[Running Sum]
    )
VAR Result =
    DIVIDE( Scores[Running Sum], Total )
RETURN
    Result
```

This is the resulting table

| Score Range | tier | Distribution | Status | General Index | Running Sum | percent | cumulative percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-100 | Tier III | 38 | Gains | 1 | 38 | 0.6% | 0.6% |
| 100-125 | Tier III | 33 | Gains | 2 | 71 | 0.5% | 1.1% |
| 125-150 | Tier III | 49 | Gains | 3 | 120 | 0.8% | 1.9% |
| 150-175 | Tier III | 46 | Gains | 4 | 166 | 0.7% | 2.7% |
| 175-200 | Tier III | 76 | Gains | 5 | 242 | 1.2% | 3.9% |
| 200-225 | Tier II | 135 | Gains | 6 | 377 | 2.2% | 6.1% |
| 225-250 | Tier I | 348 | Gains | 7 | 725 | 5.6% | 11.7% |
| 250-275 | Tier I | 417 | Gains | 8 | 1142 | 6.7% | 18.4% |
| 275-300 | Tier I | 541 | Gains | 9 | 1683 | 8.7% | 27.1% |
| 300-325 | Tier I | 682 | Gains | 10 | 2365 | 11.0% | 38.2% |
| 325-350 | Tier I | 910 | Gains | 11 | 3275 | 14.7% | 52.8% |
| 350-375 | Tier I | 781 | Gains | 12 | 4056 | 12.6% | 65.4% |
| 375-400 | Tier I | 754 | Gains | 13 | 4810 | 12.2% | 77.6% |
| 400-425 | Tier I | 551 | Gains | 14 | 5361 | 8.9% | 86.5% |
| 425-450 | Tier I | 396 | Gains | 15 | 5757 | 6.4% | 92.9% |
| 450-475 | Tier I | 214 | Gains | 16 | 5971 | 3.5% | 96.3% |
| 475-500 | Tier I | 50 | Gains | 17 | 6021 | 0.8% | 97.1% |
| 500 + | Tier I | 2 | Gains | 18 | 6023 | 0.0% | 97.2% |
| No Score | Tier I | 176 | Gains | 19 | 6199 | 2.8% | 100.0% |
| 1-100 | Tier III | 350 | Gross | 1 | 350 | 3.0% | 3.0% |
| 100-125 | Tier III | 270 | Gross | 2 | 620 | 2.3% | 5.3% |
| 125-150 | Tier III | 404 | Gross | 3 | 1024 | 3.5% | 8.8% |
| 150-175 | Tier III | 463 | Gross | 4 | 1487 | 4.0% | 12.7% |
| 175-200 | Tier III | 465 | Gross | 5 | 1952 | 4.0% | 16.7% |
| 200-225 | Tier II | 512 | Gross | 6 | 2464 | 4.4% | 21.1% |
| 225-250 | Tier I | 599 | Gross | 7 | 3063 | 5.1% | 26.2% |
| 250-275 | Tier I | 700 | Gross | 8 | 3763 | 6.0% | 32.2% |
| 275-300 | Tier I | 897 | Gross | 9 | 4660 | 7.7% | 39.9% |
| 300-325 | Tier I | 1089 | Gross | 10 | 5749 | 9.3% | 49.2% |
| 325-350 | Tier I | 1415 | Gross | 11 | 7164 | 12.1% | 61.3% |
| 350-375 | Tier I | 1183 | Gross | 12 | 8347 | 10.1% | 71.4% |
| 375-400 | Tier I | 1104 | Gross | 13 | 9451 | 9.4% | 80.9% |
| 400-425 | Tier I | 725 | Gross | 14 | 10176 | 6.2% | 87.1% |
| 425-450 | Tier I | 535 | Gross | 15 | 10711 | 4.6% | 91.7% |
| 450-475 | Tier I | 282 | Gross | 16 | 10993 | 2.4% | 94.1% |
| 475-500 | Tier I | 67 | Gross | 17 | 11060 | 0.6% | 94.6% |
| 500 + | Tier I | 2 | Gross | 18 | 11062 | 0.0% | 94.7% |
| No Score | Tier I | 624 | Gross | 19 | 11686 | 5.3% | 100.0% |

Comment: i uploaded the pbix sample file to my github. The link for the direct download is https://github.com/SergioMurru/shared/raw/main/Pawel_L%20Running%20Sum%20%23%20and%20Running%20Sum%20%25%20based%20on%20status%20Power%20BI%20(DAX)/Pawel_L%20Running%20Sum%20%23%20and%20Running%20Sum%20%25%20based%20on%20status%20Power%20BI%20(DAX).pbix

Comment: Wow, thank you for help. This looks great!